# Bypass proxy list is not getting updated through C#

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, proxy

We have to update the exception list of proxy settings through desktop application (running on windows 7 & 10, developed in C#, .Net framework)  to bypass the local addresses.  Following code has been used. However, it's reflecting the IP address into bypass list but not refreshing on OS side.  When we manually press OK on internet explorer `(Connection-> LAN Settings-> Advanced -> Exception list)`, it actually  updates the settings on OS side and we are able to access ip on browser side.

```
System  environment: 
IE version: 11.0
.Net Framework: 4.5.2
OS: Windows 7, 10
```

Is there any way that actually commit/update the proxy bypass list?

I have followed the instructions of https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1223511/Csharp-Programming-Enable-Disable-Proxy-IP.

```
        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", "ProxyOverride", _proxyByPass);


        // Forcing the OS to refresh the IE settings to reflect new proxy settings.
        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

Comment: I believe you have changed the registry.  Did you use Regedit to verify the registry was changed.

Comment: Yes, I have verified using Regedit and it getting new value. But not reflected when we hit that ip on browser

Comment: Check to see if IP is being used by any application by opening cmd.exe and type > Netstat -a which will give a list of UDP and TCP active connections.